# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Tags: java, substring

I am trying to read some words from TXT file and I am getting this error: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 . I have no idea what is wrong, probably something with begin and end index... Do you know how to fix that indexes? pls... Thanks...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
* Write a description of class Zoznam here.
* 
* @author (your name) 
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/
public class Sklad
{
Tovar tovar;
ArrayList<Tovar> potrZoznam = new ArrayList<Tovar>();

String aDruh;
String aVaha;
String aKrajinaPôvodu;
String aCena;
int i;

//    /**
//      * Constructor for objects of class Zoznam
//      */
//     public Zoznam()
//    {
//          
//    }

public int getSkladDlzka() 
{
    return potrZoznam.size();
}

public void pridajPotravinu(String paDruh, String paVaha, String paKrajinaPôvodu, String paCena) throws IOException 
{
    Tovar a1= new Tovar(paDruh, paVaha, paKrajinaPôvodu, paCena);
    potrZoznam.add(a1);       
}

public void nacitajZoSuboru() 
throws IOException 
{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("subor.txt");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String riadok, pom;
    int i = 0;
    System.out.print("\f");

    while((riadok = in.readLine()) != null) {
        aDruh = riadok.substring(0, riadok.indexOf('/'));
        riadok = riadok.substring(riadok.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, riadok.length());
        int x = 0;

        riadok = riadok.substring(riadok.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, riadok.length());
////////////////////////////////
        aKrajinaPôvodu = riadok.substring(0, riadok.lastIndexOf('/')); //     error there
        riadok = riadok.substring(riadok.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, riadok.length());
        aCena = riadok.substring(0, riadok.lastIndexOf('/')); 
        riadok = riadok.substring(riadok.lastIndexOf('/') + 1 , riadok.length());
        i++;
        pridajPotravinu(aDruh, aVaha, aKrajinaPôvodu, aCena);
    }
    fr.close();
}

public void PridatDoSkladu() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{ 
    String aDruh, aVaha, aKrajinaPôvodu, aCena, novyRiadok;

    Scanner vstup = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("\fPRIDAŤ DO Skladu:");
    System.out.println("\nZadajte Druh:");
    aDruh = vstup.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nZadajte Vahu: ");
    aVaha = vstup.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nZadajte Krajinu Pôvodu: ");
    aKrajinaPôvodu = vstup.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nZadajte Canu");
    aCena = vstup.nextLine();

    System.out.println("\f\nVami zadane údaje sú: \n" + aDruh + ", " + aVaha + ", " + aKrajinaPôvodu + ", " + aCena + ".");
    novyRiadok = (aDruh + " " + aVaha + " " + aKrajinaPôvodu + ", " + aCena);

    PrintWriter zapisdoskladu = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("subor.txt",true));
    zapisdoskladu.print(novyRiadok);
    zapisdoskladu.println();
    zapisdoskladu.close();
    pridajPotravinu(aDruh, aVaha, aKrajinaPôvodu, aCena);

}   

public void AktualizujSubor() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{ 

    File frM = new File("subor.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("subor.txt");
    int a = getSkladDlzka();
    for (int i =0; i<a ;i++)
    {
        String novyRiadok = (potrZoznam.get(i).getDruh() + " " + potrZoznam.get(i).getVaha() + " " +  potrZoznam.get(i).getKrajinaPôvodu() + "," + potrZoznam.get(i).getCena());

        PrintWriter zapisdoskladu = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("sklad.txt",true));
        zapisdoskladu.print(novyRiadok);
        zapisdoskladu.println();
        zapisdoskladu.close();
    }

    fw.close();
}   

public void Vypis(int i)
{ 
    System.out.printf("%-20d. %-20s %-30s %-10s ",i+1, potrZoznam.get(i).getDruh() + " " + potrZoznam.get(i).getVaha() + " " +  potrZoznam.get(i).getKrajinaPôvodu() + "," + potrZoznam.get(i).getCena());
}

public void zoradPodlaCeny()
{
    boolean Zamena;
    do{
        Zamena=false;
        for (int i=0;i<potrZoznam.size()-1;i++)
        {
            if (potrZoznam.get(i).getCena().compareToIgnoreCase(potrZoznam.get(i+1).getCena())>0)
            {
                Tovar tovar = potrZoznam.get(i);
                potrZoznam.set(i, potrZoznam.get(i+1));
                potrZoznam.set(i+1, tovar);
                Zamena=true;
            }
        }
    } while (Zamena);
}
```

}

Comment: Which **line** is throwing that exception?

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: I marked it in code. ^_^     aKrajinaPôvodu = riadok.substring(0, riadok.lastIndexOf('/'));

Comment: `lastIndexOf` returns `-1` if it can't be found in the `String`.

Comment: Hint: the primary language here is English. That is even true for source code, so not having "English" sources simply reduces your chances of quick/good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simply that your code makes **many many** assumptions about the "layout" of the incoming string.

You see, all these methods such as indexOf(), or lastIndexOf() return -1 when there is no such index.

In other words: **before** processing your strings and using "indexes" for substring calls ... you have to **validate** your assumptions about the layout of your incoming string!

For example by doing things like

```
int index = whatever.indexOf("/");
if (index != -1) { 
...
```

or you do some "initial" validation; for example using a regular expression.

Long story short: there are two ways when "substring'ing" from strings: either you *first* make sure that all the things you are looking for are there ... or you *deal* with such exceptions that tell you: incoming string not matching the expectations you put down in your code!